# Mustache.js renders undefined objects with newline

Tags: javascript, mustache

Here is my dummy template:

```
{{#To}}<br />&#09;  "To": "{{To}}" {{/To}}
{{#From}}<br />&#09;  "From": "{{From}}" {{/From}}
{{#Subject}}<br />&#09;  "Subject": "{{Subject}}" {{/Subject}}
<br />"Thank you for contacting us"
```

I'm expecting the rendered template to not include any of the lines if the corresponding key is missing.

However, if for instance `From` is missing, I instead get an empty line. So my final result will look like:

```
"To": "My Name"

"Subject": "Testing"
"Thank you for contacting us"
```

How come?

Comment: The line breaks (`\n`) after first and second lines are still included

Comment: It works as you want for me https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/vkxqy3yg/ !